# robovm cannot initialise on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, robovm

I have added a ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK system variable already.

```
Plugin 'org.robovm.intellij' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: org/robovm/compiler/log/Logger : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 [Plugin: org.robovm.intellij]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:130)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:77)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.robovm.idea.components.setupwizard.LicenseDialog.<init>(LicenseDialog.java:35)
    at org.robovm.idea.components.RoboVmApplicationComponent.displaySetupWizard(RoboVmApplicationComponent.java:57)
    at org.robovm.idea.components.RoboVmApplicationComponent.initComponent(RoboVmApplicationComponent.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:568)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:354)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:481)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/robovm/compiler/log/Logger : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:259)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:255)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:231)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, but on Mac.

I have solved it by updating my Java from 1.7 to 1.8!

In this [video](https://robovm.com/intellij-ideaandroid-studio-robovm-plugin-released/), it says that before installing the RoboVM plugin, you should do some configurations, in particular choose Java 1.8 for JDK.

Also, here is the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robovm/6wCM4qxgxUQ) to the same problem on RoboVM Google Group!